# Magento: Adminhtml Block rewrite is getting Mage_ appended to front of block class name

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, block, adminhtml

I am running into an issue, but I can't seem to reason through why this issue is happening. I am getting an error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Zeon_Checkout_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Export' not found in /var/www/html/transcat/transcat-development/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 146
```

I have a simple block class that is attempting to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form:

```
class Zeon_Checkout_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form
```

In my config.xml, I have the following rewrite:

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <system_config_form>Zeon_Checkout_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form</system_config_form>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

So can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Why is Magento searching for my class in the Mage namespace?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few minutes after posting this I had my buddy code review this and we quickly found that my mistake should have been obvious. Total oversight. I never declared the block class in the  node (I've gotten use to Magicento doing this for me and since I was building off another developer's module I didn't even think to check if this was set up already.) Thus Magento fell back to the Mage namespace and couldn't find the block class there either, thus throwing the above error. Adding in the block class declaration fixed the issue.